# Pressure dropped in vacuüm chamber after vacuuming the chamber and closing it. How?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, vacuum

I was doing a leak test for a low vacuüm application by vacuuming a small chamber to 60 mbar and then measure the pressure for 16 hours at constant temperature. I chose 60 mbar to prevent evaporation of humidity still left in the chamber. To my suprise when I closed the valve at t0 the pressure in the room decreased. The only things I can think of that reduce the pressure in a sealed chamber are condensation, absorption and adsorbption (and a black hole but I ruled out that one). But all 3 increase with pressure and I just decreased the pressure. Can anyone explain this pressure drop to me? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Was the chamber still connected to the vacuum pump? If yes, what type of pump was it? Was there a change in the temperature not just ambient but associated with the apparatus?

Comment: Could well be that the chamber was cooling down.

Comment: The chamber was sealed of from the environment at t = 0, I disconnected the pump in the minute after and made sure the other side of the seal was at 1 atm. I measured the temperature on the wall of the vacuümchamber and used the ideal gas law to calculate what the pressure would be at 20 C. The temperature only varied a few degrees. That would be the difference between 291 Kelvin and 295 Kelvin. I don't expect a lot of pressure difference because of that.

Comment: What type of gauge? Where is it? 40 Torr isn’t very low pressure.

Answer (score 0):

A theory I came up is that during vacumation of the chamber adsorbed molecules get loose from the walls of the chamber. When the room is sealed there are a lot of places on the wall molecules can adsorb on. I am still not satisfied with this answer however. Because most adsorption isotherms increase with pressure, for example langmuir isotherm sais theta = K*P. I vacuumed the chamber down to 60 mbar. I didn't increased the pressure up to 60 mbar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).